# How do I overlap a div with a div when using :hover?

Tags: html, hover, overlap

I have been searching all over the web and I can not find anything.

I have these three div's and when I hover over the first or the second div it moves the div's below. I want the div to overlap instead of moving it.

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="test">First
    <div>
        IP: 0.0.0.0<br>
        LOCATION: Place<br>
    </div>
</div>

<class="test">Second
    <div>
        IP: 0.0.0.0<br>
        LOCATION: Place<br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">Third
    <div>
        IP: 0.0.0.0<br>
        LOCATION: Place<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS code:

```
.test{
background-color:green;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid black;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
width:100px;
font-family:Courier;
}

.test div{
display:none;
text-align:left;
}

.test:hover div{
display:block;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `position:absolute;` and give the div you want to display overlapping an absolute position.

```
.test div{
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: ...px;
left: ..px;
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves you problem (Click he tick below the vote number) thanks :)